# nginx return while keeping the url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

We have a situation at work where we are trying to keep the url while routing to the index.html file on the same server.

https://myserver.com/ad/987987
we want to route to 
https://myserver.com/ad/index.html but keep the original url

things that I have tried:

```
location ~ ^/ad/([0-9]+) {
  return 301 https://$server_name/ad/index.hmtl;
}
```

- route change works but it changes the url

```
location ~ ^/ad/([0-9]+) {
  proxy_pass https://$server_name/ad/index.html;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

- returns a 404

```
location ~ ^/ad/([0-9]+) {
  rewrite "(/ad/[0-9]+)" /ad/index.hmtl;
}
```

- returns a 502

I'm not sure where to go with it from here.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the original URL"?  Keep it where?

Comment: Is 987987 a folder or a file? Is it loaded directly as an html file or is it something like an image? Is this a single URL is or it anything in the "ad" folder? You need to be more precise about your goal.

Comment: Brad by keep it. I mean keep the original url in the browser and not show the redirected one.

Comment: Tim  987987  it is neither.  It's the id of an entity in our system.  My developer wants the index.html file loaded so that js can be used to parse the original url to obtain the entity id.  Then supply the content to the screen based on that id..  We have a node base single page app.

Comment: In your first example, you mentioned: **return 301 https://$server_name/ad/index.hmtl;** index.hmtl seems to be a typo and should be index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are looking for this:

```
location ~ ^/ad/([0-9]+) {
    try_files /ad/index.html;
}
```

This makes nginx look for `/ad/index.html` for every URL matching the pattern in `location` statement.